# Haxe : Override `Dynamic` class attribute type

Tags: dynamic, types, attributes, haxe, phaser-framework

I'm using Haxe targeting javascript using the [phaser](http://phaser.io) game framework.

This framework has a `Sprite` class that can benefit of two different physics engines (but not both), either `Arcade` or `P2`.

I am extending it like this :

```
class Player extends Sprite {

    public function new() {
        super(/* ... */);
        game.physics.enable(this, Physics.ARCADE); // choose the engine to use on this sprite
        body.velocity.x = 500; // use the physics engine through the body attribute
    }
```

Because it's a javascript framework, the `body` attribute will either become a `Arcade.Body` or `P2.Body` depending on which physics engine you bind to the sprite.

So `body` is typed as `Dynamic` in the `Sprite` class definition and I would like to specify in my `Player` class whether it is a `Arcade.Body` or `P2.Body` so I can benefit of auto-completion and type safety.

My research so far :

- I tried to override the attribute like `var body: Arcade.Body`. Compiler's not happy about it
- I used a local variable in every method of `Player` like `var arcadeBody = cast(body as Arcade.Body)`. Not elegant, redundant

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Store `arcadeBody` as a class-level variable instead of doing it in every function as a local variable? I can't think of an elegant solution off the top of my head.

Comment: I will stick with this solution. I just wanted to know if there was any fancy way to do this in Haxe

Comment: I just deleted my answer after looking up the usage of `haxe.extern.EitherType`, because it doesn't really fit here. It's only suitable for definitions of arguments for external functions that may take arguments of multiple types. I'm thinking, I'm thinking :\

Comment: The only sane way out I see so far is subclassing the `Sprite`, once per physics system. That way you can be sure what physics body your `Sprite` actually contains.

Comment: I thought of this solution, but I think over all the solutions I like the idea of the arcadeBody: arcade.Body = cast(body, arcade.Body) class attribute. Simple enough, and does the job

Comment: @YannP well in s game that should work alright, I was thinking of a framework-grade solution. But even in a game i would subclass `Sprite` to typecast `body` automatically.

Comment: @D-side I subclassed it. But I still have to use another name for the "body" attribute because I cannot override the type of the parent class. Thanks

Comment: @YannP a chance to come up with a better name, huh :D Write an answer on what you did eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the issue using a class attribute that is a reference to `body`, but using cast.

```
var arcadeBody: Arcade.Body;

public function new() {
   //...
   this.arcadeBody = cast(this.body, Arcade.Body);
}
```

As @D-side pointed out, it is also possible to subclass `Sprite` from an `ArcadeSprite` class that is given a casted `body` attribute.